# session file naming

Tags: php

The session files are saved at `session_save_path().'/sess_'.session_id()`.

Is 'sess_' hard-coded?

If it can be specified, how do I do that?

Comment: If you've found an answer, submit an answer and accept it. Don't edit your question to include the answer, that's not how SO is meant to work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, `sess_` is a hard-coded prefix for the session file name. You can see that in the [source file *mod_files.c*](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=ext/session/mod_files.c;hb=HEAD):

```
#define FILE_PREFIX "sess_"
```

Comment: Thanks. This let's me define a proper cleanup for my custom session directory ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654310/cleanup-php-session-files

Answer (score 1):

I *think* it's hard-coded - at least, I can see no configuration option or parameter to control this.

The manual page for [`session_save_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) provides a full example for a custom handler. If all else fails, you can use that to implement your own handler, and change the naming format there.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found on http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php. It's hard-coded.

Comment: Where on the page does it say that?