# Session Files Not Getting Cleaned Up

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cleanup php session files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654310/cleanup-php-session-files)

A lot of session files seem to be building up in my sessions folder (`/home/mysite.com/sessions`), even after the session expires. Do I need to manually clear these out?

I was going to write a cron job, but I can't tell which session files are active, and I don't want to just kill them all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you need to manually clean them up because you've [setup your own *session save path*](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path). You can check the age of a file and delete if it's older than x days/minutes whatever:

```
cd /path/to/sessions; find -cmin +24 | xargs rm
```

Taken from the note part of `php.ini`:

```
; NOTE: If you are using the subdirectory option for storing session files
;       (see session.save_path above), then garbage collection does *not*
;       happen automatically.  You will need to do your own garbage
;       collection through a shell script, cron entry, or some other method.
;       For example, the following script would is the equivalent of
;       setting session.gc_maxlifetime to 1440 (1440 seconds = 24 minutes):
;          cd /path/to/sessions; find -cmin +24 | xargs rm
```

See as well this related/duplicate question: **[cleanup php session files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654310/cleanup-php-session-files)**

---

"Single" command:

```
find /path/to/session -name sess_* -cmin +24 -exec rm {} \;
```