# Run script when session ends

Tags: php, session, garbage-collection, cron

I am looking at how I can run a script or function when a user's session ends so that I can delete temporary files which may be required.

I have searched around SO to find a solution to this problem and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416159/php-run-a-script-when-a-session-expires/8416232#8416232) but I find I am a little out of my depth and I find the PHP documentation regarding GC to be confusing (and from what I understand from the documentation - it is not really what I need).

I looked at the page on [`session_set_save_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) and came up with this:

```
session_set_save_handler( '', '', '', '', 'deleteDocs');
function deleteDocs()
{
    rmdir('user/' . rawurlencode($_SESSION['data']['user']['details']['email']) . '/temp');
}
```

However, this function does not run at all. Frankly, with this, I feel like I do not know what I am really doing.

I tried using GC and looked at [`session.gc_divisor`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor) and [`session.gc_probability`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) but I cannot edit php.ini anyway.

Can this be achieved. Should I be using a cron job - if so, how can I check that sessions are finished?

Comment: `session_set_save_handler` is for replacing PHP's normal session handling with your own custom solution. It's not for chaining functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I be using a cron job - if so, how can I check that sessions are finished?

Yes. You do this based on the file last modification time (in your case the file is a directory). If it's older than the maximum session age, delete the directory.

You can use the [`find`<sup>*Wikipedia*</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find) command for that.

You find an example script in your PHP folder, see as well [Deleting old session files from custom set session folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7652780/367456) and [cleanup php session files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/654310/367456).

Comment: How do I know the maximum session age?

Comment: How long are lasting the sessions on your site? That's merely a question how *you* configure it, so you must say ;) You probably want to delete the directories after 6 hours.