# Delete Session files automatically in PHP

Tags: php, file, session, delete-file

I want to delete session files automatically in PHP.

I came to know that I have to change the following configurations in PHP.ini

- session.gc_probability
- session.gc_divisor
- session.gc_maxlifetime

But I am not sure that what value to change in these properties.

Comment: If you keep the PHP save session path to default, PHP should automatically clear them up. If you change the path, you have to clean it yourself.

Comment: What do you mean automatically? After a certain time period or when the user logs out?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654310/cleanup-php-session-files) has useful information about the automatic session file cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this example will help you

```
 <?php 
 // you have to open the session to be able to modify or remove it 
 session_start(); 

 // to change a variable, just overwrite it 
 $_SESSION['variable_name']='variable_value'; 

 //you can remove a single variable in the session 
 unset($_SESSION['variable_name']); 

 // or this would remove all the variables in the session, but not the session itself 
 session_unset(); 

 // this would destroy the session variables 
 session_destroy(); 
 ?>
```

Comment: Usually for removing the session files, there is a CRON that deletes them. Do you have full access to the server?

Answer (score -1):

Using `session_destroy();` function, created session files deleted from automatically.