# Centos /tmp directory has php*** file with large size

Tags: php, centos

I have got Cent-Os and When I have checked my **/tmp** directory I have found that a lot **php**** files** are there and they are of also big size.More interesting thing is that they are updated every-day (I got it from Last Modified date).

I found by googling "tmpwatch" can solve it but the problem is how to use it and files are modified every day and we need to give time interval in "tmpwatch" command.

**So,How to stop creating such big files and if I delete them all I afraid of system crash**

Below is the image of files are being created in /tmp :[image: files are being created in /tmp]

Comment: What is in them? Session data?

Comment: I dont know how these files are being created.

Comment: I think they are php session files

Comment: so how would i stop them?
and If I delete all of them any issue will create?

Comment: assuming that's what they are, check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654310/cleanup-php-session-files

Comment: I have checked by phpinfo and from I found session.save_path=>/tmp

Comment: Nice, then you should be set, right?

Comment: yes...now could you please tell me how to stop making this such big seesion or we cannot ?

Comment: Do you actually use sessions?

Comment: yes,i do...
it will create any site speed issue ?

Comment: No, just not really scalable, but if you don't have multiple servers, that doesn't matter. According to the php doc http://www.php.net/session.configuration You can set max lifetime and then it is seen as garbage. Make sure gc is turned on

Comment: I have checked my phpinfo,I found there session.gc_maxlifetime integer => 1440 and what is mean by gc ?

Comment: gc = garbage collection. Those params are telling the gc what to do. You could also just write a cron job to clean out that folder periodically

Comment: session.gc_probability => 1
session.gc_divisor => 100

Comment: okay....that sound interesting of making cronjob

Comment: If you get sessions that big, then you must be doing something horrible in your code. Session files contain a simple serialized array, so you could manually inspect what's in them. But I'm not sure they are session files, mine are all called something like `sess_gcmj0ejtloelktqo1s48413jr0` (on centos6, php 5.3), so the name is quite different.

Comment: @towr -> yes you are right.session file is started with prefix with "sess_" .The file I am getting is here two type 1st "sess_" => means session file and "php****" => dnt know ,what are they and why updating every day.

Comment: I think they're (partial) uploads (or at least when I do an upload php creates such files; it might possibly do so in other cases as well). You could try using the `file` command on the command-line to identify the file and see if it matches things you allow to be uploaded (say, images, or zip or pdf). It's probably uploaded files that didn't get processed properly post-upload (because of user-abort or script-failure).

Comment: @towr => how to find and what to find .Is it from shell?

Comment: I've got the same file in my tmp folder. My php session save path is not the tmp directory so it must be something else. Any news on this?

Comment: any one find what was that ? i have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

this files are related to io . 
since i am using "fopen($filePath, 'rb')" in my code , these files are creating by system and will be delete automatically (if it has enough space on /tmp folder)

if you want to change /tmp for these type of file you can change below params in your .ini file and restart apache

upload_tmp_dir='/tmp2/'
sys_temp_dir='/tmp2/'

and be sure your folder has 777 + t permission , and user/group can be 'root'