# Whats the maximum number of php session files in "session.save_path"

Tags: php, session-cookies

Whats the maximum number of files that php can handle in the "session.save_path" directory, when "session.save_handler = files" is used?

Actually we had problems, when the number of files reaches a high level. 
I cannot tell you the number we had, because I cleaned out te folder.

Users tried to log in, but where kicked out right after their first klick within the application.

Comment: PHP doesn't impose any limit on the number of session files, but filesystems do have limits after which performance begins to take an adverse hit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no specific hard-limit on the PHP side. However, most file systems perform badly when they have huge directory entries.

You possibly want to split your session files in subdirectories, as [the manual explains](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path):

> `session.save_path string`
>
> `session.save_path` defines the argument
> which is passed to the save handler. If you choose the default files
> handler, this is the path where the files are created. See also
> session_save_path().
>
> **There is an optional N argument to this directive that determines the number of directory levels your session files will be spread
> around in. For example, setting to '5;/tmp' may end up creating a
> session file and location like
> /tmp/4/b/1/e/3/sess_4b1e384ad74619bd212e236e52a5a174If**.

Beware that you first need to create the directory tree yourself. It shouldn't be difficult to write a PHP script to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! Assuming you're right, it maybe that the ext4 file system had a problem handling the number of files within the directory.

Comment: BTW, next time it happens I suggest you verify the modification date of session files. I once found a crowded session directory due to a misconfigured system that was simply not removing old data. I had session files that hadn't been touched in months.

Comment: Hi, you are right, this is what happend. I fixed it by adjusting 
    session.gc_probability,
    session.gc_divisor,
    session.gc_maxlifetime. See:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654310/cleanup-php-session-files