# Handling session_regenerate_id() in ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, session

I want to secure a little bit my application, especially I want to improve the way how sessions are handled. So, at this moment I know several facts:

1. `session_regenerate_id(false)` does not destroy old session
2. `session_regenerate_id(true)` destroys old session. With ordinary page reloads there is nothing wrong with using `session_regenerate_id(true)`.

However when making dozens **concurrent** AJAX requests there may be a
    problem which results in an error message `object destruction failed`.

So, there is nothing left to do, then to use
    `session_regenerate_id(false)` in AJAX request.

But what is needed, is to somehow mark previous **outdated** sessions, which become outdated as a result of invoking `session_regenerate_id(false)`, as "zombie" sessions that will somehow be destroyed and not litter the sessions folder.

I need some practical advice on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

All session cleanup, including those with regenerated IDs, is handled by PHP's session garbage collector.  There is nothing special needed when calling `session_regenerate_id(false)` to remove old sessions from storage.

[PHP's settings](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) for `session.gc_probability`, `session.gc_divisor`, and `session.gc_maxlifetime` apply.

You can also run your own session storage cleanup based on [last access time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654310/cleanup-php-session-files).