# Manage multiple session in PHP

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Is there a way in PHP to get informations about all sessions of users connected on my server ?

**For example :**

- User 1 logged in to my server with user info : **login = "user1"** and **corpId= "test1"**
- User 2 logged in to my server with user info : **login = "user 2"** and **corpId = "test2"**

Each time a user is logged in, user info's are stored into $_SESSION .

**Problem to solve :**

When a user calls login API, I would like to be able to check if exist (or not) a session where a user is connected with the same corpId.

**Test Example :**

```
User 3 (corpId="test3") calls login API. Result = SUCCESS
User 4 (corpId="test2") calls login API. Result = FAILED 
(cause="ALREADY_EXISTING_SESSION)
```

Comment: you can use a database to manage connections?

Comment: database is the best way to manage session data...

Comment: @Martin Ok, i will manage connection using a database. Certainly PostGreSql which is already deployed on my server. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**NOTICE:** *I think that the correct approach should be using a database to manage the connections, as pointed out by @Martin at the comments. I'm answering this just to give a different approach.*

All running PHP sessions are saved in a file on [a folder](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-save-path.php), until they are destroyed (take alook at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654310/cleanup-php-session-files)). You could read all the session files in that folder, decode them and check if there is already a session file whith that `corpId`. Here is an example using the default `save_path` in CentOS.

```
<?php
session_start();

$session_files = glob("/tmp/sess_*");

$corpIds = array();
foreach($session_files as $session_file) {
    $session_data = @file_get_contents("$session_file");
    if($session_data === false)
        continue;
    session_decode($session_data);
    if(!in_array($_SESSION["corpId"], $corpIds))
        $corpIds[] = $_SESSION["corpId"];
}

print_r($corpIds);

?>
```