# How to configure PHP for automatical regular removing of session data / sess_ files?

Tags: php, session, configuration, garbage-collection, php-7

The PHP session data is stored on the server side in `sess_{$hash}` files in the directory defined in the `session.save_path` setting of `php.ini`.

If my understanding is correct, these files should get removed after a defined period of time. How to get and how to set this time? I tried settings `session.cache_expire` and `session.gc_maxlifetime`. E.g. I set `session.cache_expire` to `2` (minutes), but after two minutes the files are still there. I also set `session.gc_maxlifetime` to `120` (seconds). But this also didn't work.

**How to configure PHP to get the `sess_*` files being removed after a defined period of time?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cleanup php session files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654310/cleanup-php-session-files)

Comment: No. But the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60229608/2019043) to this question does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `session.gc_maxlifetime` is what defines when sessions data is marked for garbage collection (*not necessarily when it's deleted*). The actual deletion of that data depends on a number of variables. Most prominently the `session.gc_probability` and `session.gc_divisor`. The **probability** over the **divisor** determine the chance that the session initialization process will invoke the garbage collector to clean up marked garbage. By default they are `1` and `100`, respectively (*meaning there is a 1% chance the garbage collector will clean up*).

This is PHP's default mechanism for garabage collection of session data. However, on some systems (*most notably Ubuntu*) the default session GC is replaced by an external cleanup mechanism which is implemented as a cron job that runs regularly to clean up session files based on stat calls and the `session.gc_maxlifetime`.

You tend not to notice these side effects on a busy site, as the number of `session_start()` calls increase, the probability that stale session data is regularly cleaned up increases. However, on a low traffic site (namely your development environment) this probability drops significantly enough that you might notice stale session data hanging around for a while. This is typically not something to be concerned with. As long as you are deleting the session cookie and regularly using `session_destroy()` when the session needs to be deleted, this is all moot.